# Testing Valuation, Size and Momentum (proprietary factors) from 1988-2013: No evidence of driving cross-sectional returns

Tags: equities, backtesting, portfolio-management, regression, factor-models

I am currently testing whether three proprietary factors - *Valuation, Size and Momentum* - explain cross-sectional returns. A sample of 3000 securities was tested using  Fama-MacBeth two-pass regressions over the period 1988-2013. In order to mitigate any thorny estimation problems due to time-varying regression slopes, I have used 50 portfolios sorted on size and book/market (25), and size and momentum (25), as test assets (LHS variables).

The unconditional regressions resulted in **insignificant** premia for the three factors. Since these factors might behave differently in disparate market conditions, I have also performed conditional regressions based on regimes. The hypothesis was that *Valuation* should be highly significant in a *Bear* market, while *Momentum* should have a statistically significant premia in *Bull* markets. However, the results showed **insignificant** premia for all factors across all market regimes.

I am a bit surprised by the results, and made me question the actual testing methodology.

For a sanity check for the methodology, I have decided to test the Fama-French factors HML and SMB using the same sample period used in the Fama-French(1993) paper. The data was downloaded from Kenneth French website.
However, even in this case, the Fama-MacBeth procedure was **unable to discover** any significant premia for either HML or SMB factors.

Would anyone have any thoughts on this issue?

Here is the code for the Fama-MacBeth procedure using **50 portfolios as test assets**. The 50 sorted portfolios, as well as the factor-mimicking portfolios - VAL, SIZE and MOM - are constructed using a sample of 3000 securities.

- In the first pass of Fama-MacBeth (time-series regression), betas are estimated using rolling windows of 60 months each. Betas are updated monthly.
- Securities are sorted at the end of June each year, and test portfolios' returns are computed from July to June of the next year.
- The returns on the factor mimicking portfolios (VAL, SIZE and MOM) are computed as the top-bottom spread of 5 book-to-market quantiles, 5 market-cap quantiles, and 5 momentum quantiles respectively.
- In the second-pass of Fama-MacBeth, the previously estimated betas of portfolios are used as independent variables in monthly-cross-sectional regressions, on a subsequent sample period. The premiums for VAL, SIZE and MOM are estimated monthly. When all the monthly cross-sectional regressions have been done, the mean of the time-series of premiums is estimated for each factor. This is all performed by the function **pmg()**. The average premiums are then tested for statistically significant difference from zero using the t-statistic.

  - The conditional regressions based on market regimes is **not** included in the code. The reason being is that the *regime* definition is also proprietary. All you need to know is that when the cross-sectional regressions are evaluated, the time-series of premiums for each factors are averaged on a *per-regime* basis: in other words, you average the premiums for the periods of bull-markets, and periods of bear-markets, ... separately. The *bull* and *bear*, and ..  premiums for each factor are tested using the t-statistic.

Please be mindful that this is only a representative **(modified) snapshot** of the code.

```
    ##########################################################################
    ###                   Time-Series Regressions                          ###
    ##########################################################################

    portfolios = 50      ## Test assets
    num.factors = 3      ## VAL, SIZE and MOM
    rows = nrow(ret.ff.zoo) - 60 + 1     ### Number of time windows
    beta.mat <- matrix(nc = num.factors + 1, nr = portfolios*rows)
    portfolio.id = matrix(nc = 1, nr = portfolios*rows)
    d = 1

    for(i in seq(1:portfolios)) {              
         ######### Dataset (merging test assets' returns and returns of factor-mimicking portfolios
         data = merge(return = ret.zoo[,i], VAL = df$VAL, SIZE = df$SIZE, MOM = df$MOM, all = c(TRUE, rep("FALSE", num.factors)))  ## "df" is the dataframe (zoo object) containing the returns of VAL, SIZE and MOM only       

        ############ Coefficients of regression
        reg = function (z) coef(lm(return ~., data = as.data.frame(z)))
        beta = rollapply(data, width = 60, FUN = reg, by.column = FALSE, align = "right")
        beta.mat[d:(d+rows-1),] = beta
        portfolio.id[d:(d+rows-1),] = i
        d = d + rows
    }
    beta.df = data.frame(port = portfolio.id, date = index(beta), beta.mat)
    colnames(beta.df) <- c("portfolio", "date", "intercept", colnames(beta)[-1])


    ##########################################################################
    ###                  Cross-Sectional Regressions                       ###
    ##########################################################################

    ## requires library(plm)

    return <- matrix(ret.zoo[which(index(ret.zoo) >= beta.df$date[1]),], ncol = 1)
    dataset <- cbind(beta.df, return)
    fpmg <- pmg(return ~ VAL + SIZE + MOM, data = dataset, index = c("date", "portfolio"), na.action = na.omit)
    summary(fpmg)
```

Thank you,

Comment: This is interesting... Would you be prepared to publish the code (I suppose you do it in R)?

Comment: Of course, I will post the code for the Fama-MacBeth procedure (time-series & cross-sectional). However, I am unable to post the code involving the construction of the factors, and their adjustments for autocorrelation, stationarity, .., since these are proprietary factors.

Comment: I am also running the Fama-MacBeth regressions using individual securities instead of portfolios as test assets. I will post that code as well.

Comment: That's really an interesting question @Mayou! Can you post the methodology or the papers links to which you inspired for that research?

Comment: I am not a quant but I happen to stumble on the website and got curious. In my highly unqualified view I suspect you'll get significant results by excluding Beta from the screen -- if/when the stock shoots up big in a down market Beta is neutralized, so it understates the momentum.

Comment: Do you normalize or winsorize the factors? Are you using 60 months of daily data or 60 months only?

Comment: You also should apply a market cap weighting scheme to the OLS.

Comment: @Mayou, a couple immediate thoughts:  (1)  what time interval are your data?  I wouldn't be at all surprised by this if you're using daily data, should be done using monthly, or weekly at a minimum.  (2)  depending on how they're assembled, your proprietary factor definitions could be driving this.  (3)  the fact that even the well established FF factors aren't producing meaningful results (though, I prefer AQR factor returns to FF) suggests there's a fundamental flaw in your methodology that's to this point obscured given your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I think your best shot is to share with us your 3,000 stocks. How far can that be from FF sample?

As a quick check I took the 25 book-to-market portfolios and the Fama-French 3 factor model and run the standard fama macbeth regressions.

1. First stage results:

[image]

Only 6 alphas are statistically significant from zero (which is good news for the model).

2. Second stage results:

[image]

As you can see the market factor (though with the wrong sign is significant).

This is however a super short sample that you used (25 years of data).